# Hash character in XML element name

Tags: xml

I'm running into an issue where I need to use a hashtag in the name of an XML node, and the hashtag is causing parsing errors. I've tried encoding the # without luck, perhaps I implemented the coding wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <properties#tags pk1="1" pk2="1" />
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameChar), `#` is not a valid character in an XML name, so it won't work. You need to find another character.

Even trying to encode with `&#35;` or `&#x23;` for `#` will not allow you to use a character that isn't valid for an XML name.